# CRON (Планировщик) - ошибка

Tags: php, хостинг, cron, cron-faq

Создал запись в планировщике на хостнге hts.ru c указанием полного пути, после чего мне на почту приходит следующее сообщение:

```
/home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php: line 1:
: command not found
/home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php: line 2: ?php
: No such file or directory
/home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php: line 3:
: command not found
/home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php: line 4: `        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Файл cron.php для InstantCMS2.2.1 выглядит так:

```
<?php

    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__);

    // Инициализация
    require_once "bootstrap.php";

    // Подключение модели
    $model = cmsCore::getModel('admin');

    // Получение списка задач для выполнения
    $tasks = $model->getPendingSchedulerTasks();

    // Если задач нет, выходим
    if (!$tasks) { exit; }

    // Коллекция контроллеров
    $controllers = array();

    //
    // Выполняем задачи по списку
    //
    foreach($tasks as $task){

        // Проверяем существование контроллера
        if (!cmsCore::isControllerExists($task['controller'])){ continue; }

        // Получаем контроллер из коллекции либо загружаем
        // и сохраняем в коллекцию
        if (isset($controllers[$task['controller']])){

            $controller = $controllers[$task['controller']];

        } else {

            $controller = cmsCore::getController($task['controller']);
            $controllers[$task['controller']] = $controller;

        }

        // Выполняем хук
        $controller->runHook("cron_{$task['hook']}");

        // Обновляем время последнего запуска задачи
        $model->updateSchedulerTaskDate($task['id']);

    }
```

Как исправить ошибки и с чем они связаны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текущей конфигурации файл просто скармливается bash-интерпретатору, который думает, что пред ним bash-скрипт. Добавьте `php` перед текущей командой (`php /home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php`), либо добавьте shebang `#!/usr/bin/env php` в начало файла.

Comment: в первом случае результат тот-же во втором /home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php: line 1: !#/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory а далее так же

Comment: нашел решение: php -f /home/srv36748/poll-decor.ru/cron.php

Comment: попутал символы в shebang, конечно `#!/usr/bin/ev php`